# Инкапсуляция в OSI протоколов IP и ICMP

Tags: ip, wireshark, icmp, osi

В общем, на уровне 3 (Сетевой) OSI работают протоколы IP и ICMP.

На уровне 4 (Транспортный) OSI работают UPD и TCP.

Так вот, пакеты более высокого уровня влаживаються в пакеты более нижнего уровня.

Я рассматриваю ping в wireshark, и он показывает, что у меня в IP пакет вложен 
ICMP пакет.

Разве может быть так, что протокол одного уровня может быть вложен в другой протокол того же уровня?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, так бывает, и один из случаев вы уже нашли. Еще аналогичный прикол есть с протоколами MPLS/IP и UDP/RTP

Comment: И еще IPSEC посмотрите как работает :-)